# How to subscribe to changes in Dexie.js + vanilla JS

Tags: dexie

This is client side code. I see [there are examples for React](https://dexie.org/#live-queries), but I am not using React. I am using preact + @preact/signals for client side state.

What is an API for subscriptions to a query in vanilla JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In https://dexie.org/docs/liveQuery()#vanilla-js it's examplified with vanilla JS (module style). If you're after a script-style, it would be:

```js
const friendsObservable = Dexie.liveQuery (
  () => db.friends
    .where('age')
    .between(50, 75)
    .toArray()
);

// Subscribe
const subscription = friendsObservable.subscribe({
  next: result => console.log("Got result:", JSON.stringify(result)),
  error: error => console.error(error)
});

// Unsubscribe
subscription.unsubscribe();
```